# No muestra los resultados correctos en mis nodos de XML usando HtmlAgilityPack con C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-scrapping, console

Actualmente tengo un proyecto en consola donde requiero hacer web scrapping de un sitio web dinamico y actualmente estoy tomando la info de ese sitio web de la siguiente forma:

Funcion para obtener el html del sitio web

```
static async Task ObtenerHtml (Calculo objeto)
{
    var html = await GetHtml(objeto);
    var data = ParseHtmlUsingHtmlAgilityPack(html);
}
```

Funcion para Obtener el html con la url especifica

```
private  async static Task<string> GetHtml(Calculo objeto)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string tipoInmu = objeto.TipoInmueble.Equals("D")? "s-departamentos-en-venta" : "s-venta-inmuebles";
    string tipoID = objeto.TipoInmueble.Equals("D") ? "xxxxxxxx" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string url = "https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.mx/" + tipoInmu + "/" + objeto.ZonaBusqueda + "/" + tipoID + "?pr=" + objeto.ValorCasa + "," + (objeto.ValorCasa + (objeto.ValorCasa * .30)) + "";
    string urlFull = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    return urlFull;
}
```

funcion donde se obtienen los nodos. (el problema esta aqui ya que cuando trato de obtener los nodos siempre me salen los mismos y deberian de ser nodos diferentes no igual, entre 25 y 30 nodos y si sale ese conteo pero con la misma info en todos los nodos.)

```
private static List<(string RepositoryName, string Description, string url,string reca,string m2)> ParseHtmlUsingHtmlAgilityPack(string html)
{
    try
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var repositories =
            htmlDoc
                .DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//body[@class='SearchPageV2']/div//div[@id='tileRedesign']/div");

        List<(string RepositoryName, string Description, string url, string reca, string m2)> data = new();

        foreach (var repo in repositories)
        {

            var precio = repo.SelectSingleNode("//span/span//span[@class='ad-price']").InnerText;
              var ubicacion = repo.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='tile-location one-liner']").InnerText.Replace(" ", "");
              var url = repo.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='tile-desc one-liner']/a").Attributes["href"].Value.Replace(" ", "");
              var recamaras= repo.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='additional-attributes-container']/div//div[@class='chiplets-inline-block re-bedroom']").InnerText.Replace(" ", "");
              var m2 = repo.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='additional-attributes-container']/div//div[@class='chiplets-inline-block surface-area']").InnerText.Replace(" ", "");
            data.Add((precio, ubicacion, "https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/" + url,recamaras,m2));
        }

        return data;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new List<(string RepositoryName, string Description, string url, string reca, string m2)>();
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tus expresiones en, por ejemplo, `var precio = repo.SelectSingleNode("//span/span//span[@class='ad-price']").InnerText;` deberían empezar con `.`, por ejemplo, `var precio = repo.SelectSingleNode(".//span/span//span[@class='ad-price']").InnerText;`, para buscar dentro del nodo de contexto `repo` y no dentro del documento completo que contiene repo.